# uploading a new version of an app in appworld

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I have an app in app world of version 1.0. That is working successfully. But now i want to upload the second version (2.0) of the app. How i upload the second version of the app in app world ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Login to appworld,
2. Click manage products
3. Click the + button under releases column corresponding to the app you want to update.
4. Answer the questions asked, and in step 4, upload your file bundles.
5. Save to draft in step 5 and then send for review

thats it ,done !!!

Comment: Once its reviewed, app will be available to the users.